# PowerShell and IE automation

Tags: javascript, powershell, browser-automation

I'm automating logging in to a website, filling in a username/password, clicking a login button and then sorting a gridview/datagrid by clicking a column header.  All using PowerShell.

I'm using code like this to fill in form elements and click on the login button and it logs in fine:

https://westerndevs.com/simple-powershell-automation-browser-based-tasks/

Here is an excerpt since I'm not at my dev PC:

```
$ie = new-object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"

$ie.Navigate("https://www.wherever.com")

while($ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000}

$sortHeader = $ie.Document.getElementById("sortHeaderDiv")
$sortHeader.click()
```

However, the last step of sorting the column of a datagrid isn't working.

Interactively, you can click on a column header and it will sort it alphabetically.  However the column header renders as DIV elements as opposed to an INPUT element, and when I'm initiating the click() event nothing happens (there is no error in the PowerShell console).

In the DOM explorer I can see that there are events bound to the DIV element which presumably call some Javascript function on click.

Is there an explanation or a workaround for this?  Thanks.

Comment: please copy the relevant code you are using in your question.

Comment: You should look into [selenium web driver](https://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: Thank you...i will.  There seem to be a few PowerShell examples for that too.  I'll report back with my findings....

Comment: FYI Selenium is more of a QA tool than an automation tool. AutoIt might be a better suggestion / consideration.